# Passing kwargs data to custom paginator with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I have a custom paginator that needs to access the `kwargs` argument `pk` given a url like this one.

`r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/stuff/$'`

Here's what I am doing right now, but it feels a little hackish.
This is my view.

```
class StuffList(ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = MySerializer
    pagination_class = MyPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.request.kwargs = self.kwargs
        return Stuff.objects.all()
```

and then, in my paginator, when the request object is passed as an argument to `paginate_queryset`, I can access the kwargs through it.

```
def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
    """Returns paginated queryset."""
    self.pk = request.kwargs.get('pk')
    pass
```

Is there another way to access it from the request object without manually adding the kwargs to it in `get_queryset`? I find it odd, because i can easily get a ton of info with the request object, but can't seem to be able to simply get the url kwargs, which forces me to add them myself. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Based on the documentation it's valid to access the kwargs on the instance object: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url

Comment: Yes but I can't access it through the pagination class instance, only in the view. I have to bind it to request first..